# use generated entities as "base class" in sf2/doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, generator

How can I tell Doctrine2 Entity Manager to use an inherited class by default, instead of the generated one?

In my new sf2 app, I generated all entities from the existing database to `/src/Package/Bundle/DataBundle/Entity` - of course I'd like to have generated forms as well, so I need for my foreign-key relations `__toString()` methods, which I don't want to put into those generated files because they get overwritten (yes they also get backuped in an extra file, so my changes aren't lost, but manually merging files is not what I want).

So I added new classes to `/src/Package/Bundle/DataBundle/Model` inheriting all from the entities, but with a `__toString()` method and surely some other tweaks in the future as well. But now, when I call         `$entity = $em->getRepository('PackageDataBundle:Customer')->find($id);` - I get an instance of `/src/Package/Bundle/DataBundle/Entity/Customer` instead of `/src/Package/Bundle/DataBundle/Model/Customer` ..

I'd like to have the behaviour from sf1, where all custom work is done in the inherited classes and the generated ones are the "base" Classes, which can be updated any time on a schema update and aren't touched otherwise..

I hope there is some configuration for this..

Maybe as a bonus, I'd like to have my naming convention turned around: to have `Model` as the "abstract" generated one and `Entity` as the actual used one

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to have the behaviour from sf1, where all custom work is done in the inherited classes and the generated ones are the "base" Classes, which can be updated any time on a schema update and aren't touched otherwise..

For purposes you described you should use [Propel ORM](http://www.propelorm.org/) - it was so in Symfony-1.4, and became even more flexible for Symfony-2.0 with Propel 1.6. It is [well documented](http://www.propelorm.org/documentation/), [easily installed](https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle) and [naturally used](http://www.propelorm.org/cookbook/symfony2/working-with-symfony2.html) within Symfony-2.0

Comment: I know Propel from the past, but got very much used to Doctrine and its DQL for mysql within sf1. I also know doctrine from older sf2 projects using MongoDB where I did not need to convert my mapping back from an existing database. So I'll take a look at propel at my next project, when there is more time to get into new frameworks :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstood your problem, but going from Propel to Doctrine i was also disappointed that there is no way to keep that "dirty" auto-generated code out of my logic.
I do not know how much it is now important to you, but I currently writing a simple bundle that implements such generation style.

```
$ app/console doctrine:generate:entities СompanySomeBundle --propel-style=true
Generating entities for bundle "СompanySomeBundle"
  > backing up User.php to User.php~
  > generating Сompany\SomeBundle\Entity\Base\User
  > generating Сompany\SomeBundle\Entity\User
```

https://github.com/madesst/MadesstDoctrineGenerationBundle

PS: Sorry for my english =/

Comment: looks promising, could you provide an english documentation on your github project as well?

Comment: @Maksim Ustinov I am using your bundle and for a while it was great! but since updating vendors in the last 6 months your bundle now throws an error. I have commented on your GitHub, would you be able to respond to me regarding this, I love your bundle and would really like to keep using it.

Comment: @Adam Wow, I did not think that someone is using this bundle. Fix for new vendors already in master, thank you!